# Selecting the "Don't Save" button using the keyboard

Tags: mac, macvim

In MacVim, when you try to close a window with unsaved changes (by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>), a window pops up to confirm, with 3 buttons:

- **Don't Save**
- **Cancel**
- **Save...**

The third one is blue, the others are gray. If I press Enter, that will trigger Save. If I press Escape, that will trigger Cancel.

[image]

How to trigger Don't Save using the keyboard? I tried selecting the button by pressing Tab or arrow keys, but none of those seem to work. My workaround is to press Escape to cancel, and close macvim with the vi command `:q!`. It would be great if I could navigate to the desired button like it's possible in many other applications.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default keyboard command for Don't Save is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⌫</kbd>  which was introduced with Lion
Prior to that it was  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>  which some apps will still respect, but not all.

*very late addition 2021 - Adobe apps still don't like Cmd/⌫  & only respond to Cmd/D*

[image: dialog]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Tab</kbd>   will switch between the options, which can then be actioned by hitting  <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>  , but **only if** you have All Controls set in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts

[image]
[image]

*Imported from my own answer at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154046/how-to-quit-without-saving-using-just-the-keyboard*

Comment: Worked like a charm, and exactly what I needed, nice touch with the All Controls stuff, thanks a lot!